# Using R 4.0.3 on macOS Catalina 10.15.7, calculating the mean of a large set of numbers yields too small result

Tags: r

I would like to create a function, which reads data out of multiple files and calculates the mean of a certain column. Therefore I created the function below.

The function has the three arguments directory, pollutant and id. Directory is part of the path to the file. The pollutant determines the column out of which the data needs to be read. The id determines which files need to be read.

To verify my results I calculated the mean in Excel, which should be 4.064 for the pollutant sulfate and the files 1 to 10. However, my result is approximately 0,62.

I tried to find the mistake I made and replicated the single steps of my function in the console to see whether they gave the correct output. The data I read in was correct and it was only out of the sulfate column. Extracting the missing values also worked properly. I believe the reason could be that the dataset is too large, because I could only view smaller pieces in the console, but even if that would be the case, I would not know how to fix that.

Could you please help me?

````
  begin <- id[1]
  end <- id[length(id)]
  
  for(id in begin:end){
    
   if(id < 10){
     
    path <- paste("/Users/X/R/", directory, "/",0,0, id, ".csv", sep="")
    dataset <- read.csv(path)
   }
    
    else if (id < 100){
      
    path <- paste("/Users/X/R/", directory, "/", 0, id, ".csv", sep="")
    dataset <- read.csv(path)
    }
    
    else {
      
      path <- paste("/Users/X/R/", directory, "/", id, ".csv", sep="")
      dataset <- read.csv(path)
    
    
    id <- id + 1
    
  }
  
  }
  
  if (pollutant == "sulfate"){
    head(dataset)
    step2 <- dataset[, c("sulfate")]
  }
  else if (pollutant == "nitrate"){
    head(dataset)
    step2 <- dataset[, c("nitrate")]
  }
  
  step3 <- step2[!is.na(step2)]
  mean(step3)
  

} ```
````

Comment: It looks like each iteration of the loop you are overwriting the previous results. You will need to storage the result of each loop in a temporary variable and then at end of the loop take the mean.

Comment: You cannot put `else` on a separate line from the previous `}`. You need `} else`. Also with some reproducible data, it would be possible to streamline your code.

Comment: @Dave2e thank you very much for your reply. Your suggestion solved my problem, thanks.

Comment: @dcarlson thank you for taking the time to review my question. Unfortunately, I was not in possession of the data and thus could not upload them.

Comment: But you can make up some data similar to the data you plan to be using.